# Lookupfields in SharePoint hosted add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, lookup-column, sharepoint-hosted-app

Is it possible to use Lookup fields in SharePoint Hosted Add-ins ?

I can add them via GUI in VS, (similar to this http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/add-lookup-field-type-column-in-list-using-visual-studio-513.aspx)

They show up in the app, but they are not connected. I can in the GUI in the app then create the same column and it works.

SharePoint-hosted apps do not support event handling so that is a no go workaround.